# How to come back to original state with a toggle button in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button like this,

```
<button class = "btn btn-group" data-toggle = "buttons" id="button" type = "button">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" id="star"></span>
</button>
```

When I click this button, I add a new CSS class called `.yellow` to change the color of the button using jQuery like this,

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
   $(function () {
      $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#star").addClass("yellow");
      });
   });

</script>
```

Now when I click again, I want to remove the `.yellow` CSS class. How can I make this possible with jQuery?

Here's a link to the code I've got so far - http://jsbin.com/dulamikiqu/edit?html,output

Comment: `toggleClass('yellow')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

`$("#star").toggleClass("yellow");`

[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) is used for adding a class to an element then removing it again once an event, such as a click, happens to that element again.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad this fixed your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$("#star").toggleClass("yellow");
```